# Add title for pointer-events:none element

Tags: html, css

I Have something like this

```html
<button style="pointer-events:none">
     <img src="" title="this should enabled"/>
     <img src="" title="some should be disabled"/>
     </button>
```

I have two images in button.

I want to give different title for each img tag where the button is having pointer-events:none class, how can we achieve this?

Comment: ideally for an image you should give alt tag, and if you want to give title, you can add the same title for button tag. It would serve your purpose

Comment: @DeepakYadav I updated my question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a title tooltip to elements within a button with `pointer-events: none`.
To make this work you can add `pointer-events: all` to each of the image elements:

```html
<button style="pointer-events:none">
    <img
        src="http://dummyimage.com/50/bad"
        title="this should enabled"
        style="pointer-events: all"
    />
    <img
        src="http://dummyimage.com/50/dad"
        title="some should be disabled"
        style="pointer-events: all"
    />
</button>
```